# Record only left channel in quicktime?

Tags: quicktime

I'm capturing some old Mini DV tapes using Quicktime. The Firewire isn't outputting audio so I'm using the headphone jack in the camera to get my audio. I plugged a standard stereo headphone into the camera and my Mic Line In. I chose my video and audio device in Quicktime. I'm getting audio in, but when I play it back I get buzzing in the right channel. I assume this is because the camera records in mono as apposed to stereo and the computer is trying to record a right channel that isn't there. I don't have a single channel headphone cord so I need a way to only record the left channel. Can I do this in quicktime?

Comment: did you take a look at app called soundflower, where you can do that.

Comment: My first assumption would be that the plugs are not the right type, the buzzing sounds more like an open ground than a non-recorded or non-existent channel.